# C# ODBC connection disposal performance

Tags: c#, odbc, database-performance

I'm trying to increase the performance of my application. When looking into the performance of the database querying, I noticed most of the calculation time in querying goes to closing and disposing a connection.
On a total query time of (on average) 76 ms, about 10 ms is used for opening the connection and exeuting the query. The other 66 ms is used for disposing the connection after exiting the `using` statement. I was wondering if it is normal that over 85% of the calculation time is used for disposing a connection. Is there any way to reduce this, which would greatly improve my performance?

My code:

```
public String executeScalarCommandString(String conString, OdbcCommand command)
        {
            //starting stopwatch here
            String result = "";
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(conString))
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    connection.Open();
                    object obj = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (obj != null && DBNull.Value != obj)
                        result = obj.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                //stop and restart stopwatch here. Avg elapsed time: 10 ms
            }
            //stop stopwatch here. Avg elapsed time: 76 ms
            return result;
        }
```

FYI: For several reasons, I'm using the outdated Access Jet engine.
I'm planning to move to SQL Server when it's possible. How would this affect my performance?

Answer (score 1):

when you want to increase the performance one do the best is using previous connections to do the task so you dont have to open and close the connections
each time you execute the command

```
public String executeScalarCommandString(String conString, OdbcCommand command)
        {
            //starting stopwatch here
            String result = "";
            // remember we have already a connection which already open
            // so we dont have to create new connection
/* we dont need this :: using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(conString))*/
            {
                try
                {
 // i'll assume the connection already on command object
                    //command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    //connection.Open();
                    object obj = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (obj != null && DBNull.Value != obj)
                        result = obj.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                //stop and restart stopwatch here. Avg elapsed time: 10 ms
            }
            //stop stopwatch here. Avg elapsed time: 76 ms
            return result;
        }
```

hope this help

Comment: To my knowledge, this is handled by connection pooling. Furthermore, I was taught it is undesirable to leave a single connection opened during runtime. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @jeroenm if you remember to dispose of it correctly at then end and the database allows multiple connections that exceed the number of users it should be fine to keep open a connection to the database

Comment: Tried this and it does greatly increase performance. Haven't encountered any problems so far either. Thanks!